# conulta mysql a Json y luego a tabla HTML con jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo esta consulta mysql a mi tabla en php(PDO)

```
 try 
 {
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
 $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM t_persona";
    $result = $connect->query($query1)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$return = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $return[] = [ 
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $row['apellido'],
        'telefono' => $row['telefono']
    ];
   }
    }catch(PDOException $e) 

   {
       print_r($e->getMessage());
   }

$connect = null; 
echo json_encode($return);
```

y en el mismo archivo "consultapersona.php mi HTML con su script js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to return JSON Data from PHP Script using Ajax Jquery</title>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <h2 align="center">Consulta Empleado</h2>

   <br />   

   <table class="class ="table-responsive table-bordered table-striped id="tabla_persona_detalle">

    <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Telefono</th>
   </tr>

   </table>
   </div>

  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

debajo del html el js

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.getJSON("$return", function(data){
     var datos_persona = '';
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
        datos_persona += '<tr>';
        datos_persona +=  '<td>'+ value.nombre+'</td>';
        datos_persona +=  '<td>'+ value.apellido+'</td>';
        datos_persona +=  '<td>'+ value.telefono+'</td>';
        datos_persona +=  '</tr>';
        });
//mostramos todo el array datos_persona dentro de la tabla
       $.('#tabla_persona_detalle').append(datos_persona);
    });

});
</script>
```

Lo que busco como habrán notado es llamar al resultado de la consulta y que fue codificado a JSON mediante JQuery e imprimirlo en una tabla HTML  llamando a su $return pero no carga nada. Creo estar llamando mal a la consulta pero no se como llamarla. Todo esta en un mismo archivo. consultapersona.php. Gracias

Comment: Existe un plugin para jQuery llamado datatables, este tiene la función que buscas, armar una tabla trayendo la data mediante AJAX

https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data

Comment: Cuantas personas se supone que devuelve el JSON una o varias?

Comment: Hola Juan Luis. Se supone que tendría que devolver todas las personas de la base de datos. Gracias